# Show tweets from people I'm following on website embedded Twitter feed

Tags: twitter

I've had a look at the following link - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines within Twitter. It says you can display your timeline, favorites, lists but not the tweets from the people you're following.

Essentially when you first log into Twitter, I want to show those tweets - the tweets from people I'm following on my website.

Or is there a way to automatically add people we're following to a list? So I can then display that list?

Can it be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with embedded timelines but you can achieve it by using the REST API.  The link below gives details on how to do this.  Your request will then return a json string of the latest tweets of people you follow.  You can format this then display it

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline